# Using DatagramSocket and DatagramPacket to "ping" a machine

Tags: java, sockets, datagram

I am using a DatagramSocket to fetch data from a server. In the process of doing this I am hoping to determine the delay between when it was sent and when it was received, essentially the ping. However when I run my code the delays I measure do not seem to be logical.

I have a `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor` with a pool of 4 threads. What I am seeing is that when I send one message I get a ping say `20ms`, fine. But when I send two messages side by side I get a ping of 40ms for both, three is 60ms and four is `80ms`. 5 of course goes back round and I get four at 80ms and one at 20ms.

This is how I'm making the requests:

```
public Future<JSONObject> sendQuery(final String addr, final int port) throws IOException {
    return app.getExecutor().submit(new Callable<JSONObject>() {

        @Override
        public JSONObject call() throws Exception {
            DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket();

            // send request
            byte[] buf = new byte[256];
            InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName(addr);
            DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(buf, buf.length, address, port);
            long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
            socket.send(packet);

            // get response
            packet = new DatagramPacket(buf, buf.length);
            socket.receive(packet);
            long end = System.currentTimeMillis();

            // set response
            String jsonStr = new String(packet.getData(), 0, packet.getLength());
            JSONObject jso = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
            jso.put("ping", (int) (end - start));

            return jso;
        }
    });

}
```

and calling them from:

```
for (ServerDefinition server: servers) {
    String addr = server.getAddr();
    int port = server.getPort();
    pending.add(clientApp.getQuerySocket().sendQuery(addr, port));
}
```

Then later on from an update loop:

```
private void initializePending() throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
    Iterator<Future<JSONObject>> it = pending.iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        Future<JSONObject> future = it.next();
        if (future.isDone()) {
            it.remove();

            JSONObject resp = future.get();

            // do some stuff
        }
    }
}
```

I am not sure why the responses are acting in the way they are and I'm hoping that it is something simple that I am overlooking.

Comment: If you are sending and receiving multiple packets, you don't appear to be checking that the response you got was to the packet you sent.  I suggest including the timestamp in the message and taking a difference with that.  btw 20 ms is pretty long unless it is to the internet.

Comment: Yeah I'm running it to my external IP, I wanted something more interesting that lots of 0ms and 1ms.

Comment: @PeterLawrey each response is coming from a different port, which is unique to each connected server.

Comment: It should be noted that I am making multiple requests to the same server (just for testing).

Comment: Multiple requests over the same port or different port numbers?

Comment: They are all going to the same port. But I can set up lots of test servers on different ports.

Comment: @Neilos If you want something more interesting, measure it in micro-seconds instead of ms (with System.nanoTime() ;)